# Was the War Boy language ever codified?

Tags: dialogue, mad-max-fury-road

In ***Mad Max: Fury Road***, Immortan Joe's War Boys seem to have their own english derivative language. It's a very pidgin slang form of modern english, that has developed over two generations or so, considering the post apocalyptic nature of the movies. Was the language ever codified as an individual, unique language form, or was it just a bunch of random words as needed, out of universe? In either case, is there a complete reference to this pidgin War Boy language?

Is there any information of how Immortan Joe, the pre-apocalypse military Colonel Joe Moore, developed the language in-universe, as he has created the entire War Boy cult/culture?

Comment: You last question about Immortan Joe might be better asked as a separate individual question. It seems rather unrelated to the whole Warboy language question. Or you might want to point out in which way they are related.

Comment: Immortan Joe created the war boys and the entire society. He created the language.